# Control-M: Persisting column layout

Tags: control-m

In Monitoring - All Jobs - List view, how can I persist the order and widths of the columns?

Right now, if I exit Control-M and logs back in, the layout is reset to default.

---

I read that I may not have write access to the location where layout information is saved. Does anyone know what the location is?

Answer (score 0):

In the Control-M GUI you can navigate to `File > Options > Advanced > Presets path`.
Ensure you have write access to this location.

[image]